# Converting polyline to raster with varying cell value along shapes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, elevation, slope, rasterization

I have a polyline file with start and end elevations. I'm trying to convert this to a raster which will have as values a gradient between the start and end elevations along the line.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the start and end verticies of your line to points and assign the appropriate heights to them.  Then interpolate a raster from that.  I don't know what you want it for so I don't know how useful this will be and be careful about inferring anything from interpolated raster values away from your line.

If you want more control (perhaps because you have several lines), you could [densify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm) the lines and use linear referencing to get the m values of the densified verticies and assign them an interpolated height value (or a simple sum as you will know the point number and the densify distance).  This way you can have other shapes to your slope by applying suitable mathematical functions.  Then interpolate a raster from these points as before.

Comment: Thanks! Densify looks like the way to go. From this I can assign a Z value, split by vertex, and convert to raster.